# How To Access DATASET DATA TABLE in ASP.NET WEB FORM APPLICATION?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, reference, datatable, namespaces, dataset

In Visual Studio 2013 asp.net web application I have a connection with my database with dataset in  app Code folder and I wrote some method for my table but I can ACCESS to user Data Table in  login code behind

```
using System;
using 

    System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.Entity;


        DataSet.UsersDataTable oUserDataTable =new DataSet.UsersDataTable();
UsersDataTable does not exist in system.data.dataset
```

Comment: instead of  DataSet.UsersDataTable oUserDataTable =new DataSet.UsersDataTable(); just write  DataSet oUserDataTable =new DataSet();

Comment: Could I email my project to you?

Comment: yes...kartikeyakhosla07@gmail.com...plz mention also ur complete problem...

Comment: I Sent My Project To your email

Comment: okk i will see to it...

Comment: i have to go somewhere right now urgently i will see ur problem as soon as possible...sorry for inconvienece....